# TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-ios, simulator

```
import {manager, ReactCBLite} from 'react-native-couchbase-lite';

ReactCBLite.init(8091, 'admin', 'admin123', e => {
    console.log('initialized');
});
```

Running this code in react-native for ios getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/react-native-couchbase-lite):

```
import Couchbase from "react-native-couchbase-lite";

Couchbase.initRESTClient(manager => {
   // use manager to perform operations
});
```

It seems there is no only init method, but there are other init methods you should use.

Pay attention that there are also special steps needed to be taken for iOS.